# how to open a file with name in a string in java

Tags: java

```
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("./abc.txt");
```

I want to replace the quoted value by a string

I also want to fill the string with different filenames in a switch statement so that I can open different files and perform repeated operations on the files data.

how do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
```

Note that there is no `String.valueOf(String)`. If there was, it would be pointless as it would likely just return the `String` you passed it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Java doesn't support `Strings` as `case` parameters (or at least you'll have to wait for Java 7 to do so), so you'll need a set of `if`/`else` comparisons to do different things for different filenames.

```
if ("a.txt".equals(filename)) {
  // do something
}
if ("b.txt".equals(filename)) {
  // do something
}
```

etc.